# PHP on Windows Include path for Zend Framework not working

Tags: php, windows, zend-framework

I know this should be real simple, but I can't get Zend Framework to work.

What I did so far:

1 - Downloaded Zend Frame Full

2 - Extracted everything to c:\php\includes\ZendFramework.

3 - Modified the php.ini file so now it shows

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path = ".;C:\php\includes;C:\php\includes\ZendFramework\library"
```

4 - Added same info to my 'path' in windows system variable, so now the relevant portions look like:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\php\includes;C:\php\includes\ZendFramework\library
```

I used the Zend InstallationChecker from http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/demos/Zend/Gdata/InstallationChecker.php and receive the following response:

> Zend Framework Installation Errors    Tested
>
> 0
>
> Exception thrown trying to access Zend/Loader.php using
>   'use_include_path' = true. Make sure you include Zend Framework in
>   your include_path which currently contains:
>   .;C:\php\includes;C:\php\includes\ZendFramework\library

I've read all sorts of install guides and I'm pretty sure I've done everything I was supposed to. Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1):

That installation checker is part of ZF1, but if you downloaded the framework fresh, you've installed ZF2. It's quite possible that everything's installed fine, and it's the installation checker that is broken (as it looks for a file that doesn't exist in ZF2).

Comment: thanks for responding. Then is there another way to check? I need to access the Google API and in my test file keep on receiving the error Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin' not found in C:\php\google_doc.php. I assumed it was a Zend install error.

Comment: Ah, the Gdata classes aren't in ZF2. Google decided to create their own standalone client libraries so they were removed. Depending on which Google service you're trying to use you'll need to use Google's own client library, e.g. https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: Thank you. There is so much info on-line that does not clearly say what is the current version. Specifically I need to read data from a non-public spreadsheet? I'm assuming this should be done with Google's own client library?